# Change Directory command in batch file is not working

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to create a batch file to do a few things for a class I'm in. Everything needed to run works but I cannot find a simple answer as to why change directory (CD) is not working for me. I can't figure it out.

My code is as follows:

```
@echo off

title NewUser

: creating a folder called "Scripts" on C:\
: add local user named: "MaxLocal" password: "student"
: create directory at the root of F:\ named "Files_for_Max"
: create ACE for user "MaxLocal" to "Files_for_Max" with: Read, read & Execute, List folder contents
: Re-establish inheritence to sub folders and files
: copies cmd.exe from C:\Windows\System32 folder to "Files_for_Max"
: add "MaxLocal" to management group created in Assignment 3
: produces ICACLS report for "Files_for_Max" called "icaclsReport.txt" in "Scripts"
: moves this .bat file to "Scripts"

mkdir "C:\Scripts"

net user MaxLocal student /add

mkdir "F:\Files_for_Max"

icacls "F:\Files_for_Max" /grant MaxLocal:(OI)(CI)RX 

copy "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "F:\Files_for_Max"

net localgroup Management MaxLocal /add

icacls F:\Files_for_Max /save C:\Scripts\icaclsReport.txt /t

move  "F:\NewUser.bat" "C:\Scripts"

pause
```

So it's the last line specifically. MOVE works great but I'm not allowed to use it for whatever reason. I have tried a ton of ways of how to do it with CD to no conclusion. I need to take this NewUser.bat file on F and move it to the newly created scripts folder. Yes I have tried the /D command but perhaps I didn't have the correct spacing or used quotes when unneeded?

Any ideas?

Comment: I do not see any `CD` command in your code.

Comment: @JosefZ: I can confirm that you don't appear to be blind.

Comment: Hold on, is this `NewUser.bat`, or is this another script?

Comment: Yes the MOVE command is where the CD is supposed to be, sorry.

Comment: the NewUser.bat is the batch file that is open I have to use CD to move it

Comment: `cd` doesn't move anything, it just changes what directory the current Batch file is looking at.

Comment: I have tried doing CD C:\Scripts thinking it would just move this file but it doesn't work. Do I have to specify the folder path I'm already in and then the destination?

Comment: can you make a minimal working example as per stackOverflow guidelines?

Answer (score 12):

```
cd /d "C:\Scripts"
```

This changes the current working directory to C:\Scripts.
If you want to instead move the Batch file itself:

```
copy "%~f0" "C:\Scripts"
(goto) 2>nul & del "%~f0"
```

This copies itself (`%~f0`) into C:\Scripts, then deletes itself, effectively a move command.
If you want you could do this:

```
copy "%~f0" "C:\Scripts"
start "C:\Scripts\~nx0"
(goto) 2>nul & del "%~f0"
```

Which also starts the copied Batch file, then it deletes itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It isn't exactly what i need to do and for whatever reason, cd /d "C:\Scripts" just will not work. But, your other conclusion does. It is very much appreciated.

Comment: Then consider accepting it as the proper answer. It shows that it fixed your problem, and others can view it if they need help.

Comment: Oh, It totally is a correct response and move does also do the desired solution along with probably many other ways. My problem is that my assignment states that for this one particular issue, I have to use CD and for whatever reason I cannot get it to run.

Comment: `cd` does not move files, it simply changes what the current process is looking at. You could do a `cd /d C:\Scripts`, `echo LINE 1 OF NEWUSER.BAT>NewUser.bat`... but that does't move or copy the file _per se_.

Comment: @ender_scythe, you've missed a closing double quote on your last examples. Also you could probably forget about the copy and delete and just replace those three lines with `(GoTo) 2>Nul & Move "%~f0" "C:\Scripts"`.

Comment: @ender_scythe, both examples, the middle one too…

Comment: @Compo Yet another idiotic mistake, thankyou for the correction.

Comment: @Shafty, what teacher or I.T. professional is telling you that you have to use the `CD` command to move a file?  Hopefully you are reading the help file for all the commands you are using.  It is pretty clear what the `CD` and `MOVE` commands do.

Comment: @ender_scythe Thank you so much. Now CD command works in batch file.

Comment: It was great help for me! To move directory and VOLUME, /d is nesessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could have used cd before the copy command, which may correspond to how you need to use it before the move command.

```
cd C:\Windows\system32
copy cmd.exe F:\Files_for_Max
```

The batch file asks "copy what where" so we have copy for copy, cmd.exe for what, and F:\Files_for_Max for where.

Similarly,

```
cd F:\
move NewUser.bat C:\Scripts
```

Should be the way it can work. So first you're moving into the directory F:\ before asking it to move the specified file, much like what I have in the copy command.